# $.support.fixedPosition removed in v1.8?

Tags: jquery

jQuery 1.7 introduced `$.support.fixedPosition`, but it somehow disappeared in 1.8. I can't find anything in the changelog. Any hints where it has been moved, or if it has been removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoth [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/):

> **Since jQuery requires these tests internally, they must be performed on *every* page load. Although some of these properties are documented below, they are not subject to a long deprecation/removal cycle and may be removed once internal jQuery code no longer needs them.**
>
> [...]
>
> For your own project's feature-detection needs, we strongly recommend the use of an external library such as Modernizr instead of dependency on properties in jQuery.support.

It seems it was indeed [simply removed](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/77536f5cb2ab042ac8be40ba59f36d8f3bd7e4d1#diff-2) sometime between v1.7.2 and v1.8.0.

Comment: Just found where it has been removed: [77536f5cb2ab042ac8be40ba59f36d8f3bd7e4d1](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/77536f5cb2ab042ac8be40ba59f36d8f3bd7e4d1#src/support.js)